# mvc route random number of parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to construct a route that routes to a specific product page.

The product exists in a category. Categories may also exist in categories. I am trying to construct the URL like

> my-site.com/products/category/category/category/product

The amount of categories is able to change but the last parameter will always be the name of the product.

Is there any way to construct a route for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A solution exactly for you

I faced the same problem in the past and solved it a bit differently to what others will advise you here. Most of solutions will talk about **catch-all* parameter. In your case this means that you'd have to parse the product out yourself. Manually. Because catch-all parameter may only be the last parameter in route definition.

### Catch-all anywhere in the route

If you think of it carefully, you can actually realise that catch all parameter can actually be defined anywhere in the route as long as you have all other segments present. So I've written such route class that does all that and successfully runs in production on a heavy traffic website.

My blog post has all the information about it as well as all the code that will **solve your problem**:

[Custom Asp.net MVC route class with catch-all segment anywhere in the URL](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html)

This makes it possible for you to define your route as:

```
products/{*categories}/{productId}
```

If you think of the catch-all parameter even further you could also get to the point that a single route definition could have several catch-all parameters as long as at least one segment between them is static. But my class isn't able to do this, because your scenario with just one arbitrary segment set is much more common.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Robert.  I have a secondary question for you.  Lets say I want to erase the product name off the end of the url. The url becomes products/category1/category2/category3.  I would like this page to be sort of a catalog page of all products in category 3.  The catalog goes up a level if you take category 3 off the url.  Do you know how to obtain routing like this?

Comment: @Justin: If your products are accessed by `productID` then you can accomplish this by providing route constraint on the last segment. If not, then only a usual catch-all definition can help you.

Comment: @Justin: You see if you can't distinguish products from categories than it's just as hart to route parser as it is to a human to know when the last segment is still a category and when it is actually a products. But Most likely you do have categories in readable strings and products in numbered IDs in which case a second route definition would suffice categories. So Put a constraint on this route definition and add another one with usual `products/{*categories}` URL definition.